# a very simple JSON call produces a JS error in console: "Unexpected token u"

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to do a simple JSON call but i can't access the JSON file and the console tell me this: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u"

this is my JSON file 'universo.json':

```
{"menu": {
  "chiave": "valore",
  "key": "value",
  "oggetto": {
    "sottoggetto": [
      {"chiave": "valore", "chiave2": "valore2"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

and this is my JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var Richiesta = new XMLHttpRequest();
        Richiesta.open('GET','universo.json',true);
        Richiesta.responseType = 'JSON';
        Richiesta.onload = function() {
                    valore = JSON.parse(this['menu']);
                    console.log('yes');
                };
        Richiesta.send();

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks you.

Comment: I'm assuming the problem stems from the line `Richiesta.open('GET', 'universo.json', true);`. Make sure the path to your json file is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `onload` handler, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is the XMLHttpRequest instance, which does not have a `menu` property. Accessing it will yield `undefined`, and `JSON.parse`ing that will stringify it and `"undefined"` is not valid JSON (begins with unexpected `u`).

Since you have set the `.responseType` to JSON already you actually don't need to parse anything. Just access the object.

```
Richiesta.responseType = 'json'; // seems to require lowercase
Richiesta.onload = function() {
    var obj = this.response; 
    // or:  = Richiesta.response
    // or:  = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // for backwards-compatibility
    var valore = obj.menu;
    console.log('yes', valore);
};
```